# What is the difference between 写完 and 写得完 ?

Tags: grammar, syntax

According to my textbook 简明汉语语法 the parts after the verb 写 are so called complements, they are strictly differentiated from adverbs.

both complements are called:

- complement of result 完
- complement of possibility 得完

I assume the meaning of 写完 is "to write (and it is completed)".
However, i can not find out myself what the difference to 写得完 is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 写得完: possible to complete writing
>
> 写完: complete writing

Beginners often learn `能+verb` first, but in many cases, `verb+得+complement` sounds much more natural when they want to express `can/be able to + verb`.

I'm aware of some languages, e.g. Japanese and sometimes English, that don't always strictly distinguish these two kinds of expressions, but Chinese does. Always keep in mind that 写得完 is **stative** while 写完 is **dynamic**.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answer is correct or contributes to your understanding, here is my interpretation:

写完, as you have put it, means some piece of writing is completed.

写的完 the stresses the `ability` to complete something written. E.g. 这么长的文章你写得完吗？ Are you `able to finish writing` such a long article/essay?

I think you already know 看得懂 where 得 is to emphasize the ability to understand something by reading (able to read and understand). E.g. 这个汉字你看得懂吗？ Can you read this Chinese character?

Comment: the negative of 写得完 would be 写不完 , right?

Comment: Much the same as 看不懂，听不懂, yes. I think you got it now.

Comment: if 写不完 is the negation of 写得完 , than i am clueless what the negative of 写完 might be???

Comment: The negation of 写完 is 不写完, i.e. `not complete writing (probably on purpose)`, which is rather uncommon and has only limited use. The usual expressions we use are 写完了 and 没写完.

Comment: That is quite 'regular', e.g.: 你写完了吗？ 我没写完。Or  if you are to state something in the present, 不写完.